# Downloads with redirect with CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, download, casperjs

Behind an Extranet website, which requires login, I need to download a statistical report that's generated by a php url with parameters https://extranet.com/report.php?date_start=AAAAMMJJ&date_end=AAAAMMJJ

This launches another URL that gives the file : https://extranet.com/export.php?f=Report_datetime.xlsx

But this URL only exist just to get the excel file. If I relaunch that export url, it's blank

I had no problem to login with CasperJS

I did this

```
casper.thenOpen('https://extranet.com/report.php?date_start=AAAAMMJJ&date_end=AAAAMMJJ', function() {
    casper.download('https://extranet.com/export.php?f=Report_datetime.xlsx','report.xlsx');
});
```

But this results in a blank file

I also tried

```
casper.download('https://extranet.com/report.php?date_start=AAAAMMJJ&date_end=AAAAMMJJ', 'report.xlsx');
```

Which resulted in a file containing only the headers.

I'm stuck.

I wish CasperJS had a default_download folder where it would download file automatically like a browser.

Comment: Sounds like a timing issue. Can you wait between your calls?

Comment: Please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors. If there are, please edit your question accordingly. Also which PhantomJS version do you use?